# How can I check an other table before updating?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have these two tables:

```
 // users
+----+-------+-----------------------+--------+
| id | name  |       email           | active |
+----+-------+-----------------------+--------+
| 1  | peter | peter12@hotmail.com   | NULL   |
| 2  | jack  | most_wanted@gmail.com | NULL   |
| 3  | john  | john_20016@yahoo.com  | NULL   |
+----+-------+-----------------------+--------+

// activate
+----+---------+---------------------+
| id | post_id |   random_string     |
+----+---------+---------------------+
| 1  | 2       | fewklw23523kf       |
+----+---------+---------------------+
```

Also I have an URL like this:

```
http://example.com/activate.php?str=fewklw23523kf
```

---

All I'm trying to do:

- Comparing `GET['str']` with `random_string` column from `activate` table
- Checking `active` column for `NULL` where `id = post_id`.

And then (if there is matched row) set `1` the `active` column from `users` table. How can I do that?

---

```
$str = $_GET['str'];

$stm = $db_con->prepare( "UPDATE users SET active = 1
                          WHERE ( SELECT 1 FROM activate WHERE random_string = ? ) t AND
                                ( SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE t.post_id = id AND
                                                            active IS NULL ) ");

$stmt->execute(array($str));
```

My query doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  join

```
UPDATE users 
INNER JOIN activate on activate.post_id = user.id
SET active = 1        
WHERE activate.random_string = ? 
AND user.active IS NULL;
```

Comment: As an advice, may you please tell me is my algorithm correct? *(to activate a new account)*

Comment: If i understand right you use a random generated string send via post for to the user so when the user click the link you send you get this value for enable the related user if is not enabled .. the   logic is right ..

Answer (score 2):

try to change

```
( SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE t.post_id = id AND active IS NULL )
```

to this

```
( SELECT 1 FROM users, activate as t WHERE t.post_id = id AND active IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do believe this one will do the trick

```
UPDATE users, activate SET active = 1 
WHERE users.id = post_id and active is null and random_string=?
```